# SO Careers: Twitter links should use HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

At the top of SO Careers pages, such as https://careers.stackoverflow.com/bittner, there is a generated Twitter link. It should use HTTPS instead of HTTP to be faster (because Twitter redirects to HTTPS) and more secure.

Comment: Moreover; Across **all** SE sites I have the annoying Firefox warning "the connection to this website is not fully secure" simply because Gravatar images are requested over HTTP (I'm using HTTPS Everywhere which turns SE sites into HTTPS)

Answer (score 1):

Done - we now use HTTPS links to Twitter profiles.